# ¿Como puedo unir dos listas simplemente enlazadas? JAVA

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

Es algo muy sencillo pero que me ha dado un poco de dolor de cabeza, soy muy novato. La idea es unir dos listas de modo que:

lista uno = 1, 3, 5

lista dos = 2, 4, 6

El resultado debería ser:

lista tres = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Ya hice el código para generar las otras dos y el dolor de cabeza va de como unirlas.

Tengo la clase lista

```
    public class listas {

    nodos primero;
    byte tamanio;

    public void Lista() {
        primero = null;
        tamanio = 0;
    }

    public boolean esVacia() {
        return primero == null;
    }

    public int getTamanio() {
        return tamanio;
    }

    public void agregarAlFinal(int dato){
        nodos nuevo = new nodos();        
        nuevo.setDato(dato);
        if (esVacia()) {         
            primero = nuevo;   
        } else{
            nodos aux = primero;
            while(aux.getSiguiente() != null){
                aux = aux.getSiguiente();
            }
            aux.setSiguiente(nuevo);
        }
        tamanio++;
    }


    public void MostrarLista(){
        if (!esVacia()) {
            nodos aux = primero;            
            while(aux != null){
                System.out.print(" [ " + aux.getDato() + " ] ");
                aux = aux.getSiguiente();
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }       
    }     
}
```

Y la clase Nodos

```
public class nodos {

    int dato, dato2;
    nodos siguiente;

    public void Nodo(){
        this.dato = 0;
        this.siguiente = null;
    }

    public int getDato() {
        return dato;
    }

    public void setDato(int dato) {
        this.dato = dato;
    }

    public void setDato(int dato, int dato2){
        this.dato = dato;
        this.dato2 = dato2;
    }

    public int getDato2() {
        return dato2;
    }

    public void setDato2(int dato2) {
        this.dato2 = dato2;
    }

    public nodos getSiguiente() {
        return siguiente;
    }

    public void setSiguiente(nodos siguiente) {
        this.siguiente = siguiente;
    }  
}
```

Y la clase principal.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        listas lista_est = new listas();
        listas lista_prg = new listas();
//        listatr3s lista_tr3s = new listatr3s();

        int est = 0, prg = 0, opc = 0;

        do{
            System.out.print("\n1. Insertar numero de estudiantes." + 
                    "\n" + "2. Insertar número de preguntas." +
                    "\n" + "3. Mostrar tamaño de listas vigentes." + 
                    "\n" + "4. Juntar las dos listas." + 
                    "\n" + "5. Darle <play> a la asignación." +
                    "\n" + "6. Salir. \n");

            System.out.print("\nOpción: ");
            opc = leer.nextByte();

            switch(opc){
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("Ingrese el número de estudiantes: ");
                    est = leer.nextByte();
                    for (byte i = 1; i <= est; i++) {
                        lista_est.agregarAlFinal(i);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("Ingrese el número de preguntas: ");
                    byte cant2 = leer.nextByte();
                    for (byte i = 0; i < cant2; i++) {
                        prg = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(cant2-1)+1);
                        lista_prg.agregarAlFinal(prg);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.print("Listado estudiantes: "); lista_est.MostrarLista();
                    System.out.print("Listado preguntas: "); lista_prg.MostrarLista();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.print("Se agrega a la tercera lista.");
//                    lista_tr3s.agregarAlFinal(lista_est, lista_prg);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Listado con la asignación: ");
//                    lista_tr3s.Mostrar3Lista();
                    break;            
            }            
        }while(opc != 6);       
    }
```

Eso me funciona perfectamente bien para generar las listas, lo que tengo entendido es que tengo que hacer otra clase para generar un TERCERA lista. Lo que se me hace dificil es realizar el código para unir las dos listas creadas.

Comment: sabes, si tenes algo de codigo publicalo, ya que aqui no somos adivinos para saber como estructuraste tu lista. y solo pon el codigo necesario y no un monton inecesario.

Comment: i pudiste?, me pasas el programa porfa

Answer (score 3):

Personalmente yo haría que la clase lista herede la clase java.util.List. 
Entonces después creas una lista nueva y usas el metodo addAll()

```
List<String> union = new ArrayList<String>();
union.addAll(listaUno);
union.addAll(listaDos);
```

Comment: El dilema es que estamos viendo lo elemental de estructura de datos, debe ser si o si con Listas y Nodos.

Answer (score 0):

puede hacerlo funcionar usando el método get en un ciclo While, el limite estará dado por la máxima cantidad de elementos en una lista "a" o "b"

```
                for(int i = 0; i<Math.max(a.size(), b.size()); i++){
                    if (i<a.size()){
                        lista.add(a.get(i));              
                        
                    } if (i<b.size()){
                        lista.add(b.get(i));
                    }
                }
```